# From an XMl file, an xml element data needs to be put into a clob column in oracle table

Tags: java

I have an xml file, from which I need to get the element  information into a clob column in oracle table.
the xml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bookstore>
  <notepad>
   Test Notepad data. Test Notepad data. 
  </notepad>
  <documents>
   werfjkhrgkhrekgjeirogvmj vreuhfgiurvhe kjhr ieu
   ndbcjhaejvh ukarehv khrkuehgvuhwrhuivg hrfjkhuirehv
  </documents>
</bookstore>
```

The notepad element information has to go into clob column in the oracle tableand the documents element information had to go into blob column in the same table.

Code written is as follows:

```
    **String notes = report.getNotepadInfo();
    System.out.println("the notes is : "+notes);**

    byte[] documentValByteArr = report.getDocumentsList().get(0).getDocumentValues().get(0).getDocumentValue().getBytes();                          
    System.out.println("documentValByteArr :"+documentValByteArr);

    //Pass the String notes to load as clob and Pass the byte[] to load as blob to LoadData class's updateDV method to update in the database.
    LoadData.updateDV(id,documentValByteArr,notes);

    enter code here 

    public static void updateDCNVersion(String Id, byte[] blob, String clob) {
      **ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);**

        // Here we run the Function to update data in the table.
        try {
            CallableStatement proc_stmt = connection.prepareCall(" {call P_UPDATE_DV(?,?,?)}");
            proc_stmt.setString(1,Id);
                     proc_stmt.setBinaryStream(2, bais, (int)blob.length);
        proc_stmt.setString(3, clob);
                proc_stmt.executeQuery();
            proc_stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: SQL Exception updating T_DV");
            System.err.println("SQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

This approach of loading String data into clob column in oracle table works perfectly.
But the Byte[] data is not loading into the blob column in oracle table?

Pls see the changed code and advise me.
Thank You Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
byte[] documentValByteArr = ..........    
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(documentValByteArr );
pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, bais , (int)documentValByteArr .length());
```

or try this

these two BLOB are not compatible you can try

```
 weblogic.jdbc.common.OracleBlob
```

Comment: This is a Java console project . I am not using any weblogic.

Comment: I am talking about jar only not application server.

Comment: I am using ojdbc14.jar.

Comment: Should I be using a different JAR.

Comment: @user2015 I update my answer with different approach, And it must work for you, as well you no need to change the jar just try above code (approach 1)

Comment: I did use it in this way,

Comment: Sir, pls see my changed code. It is not throwing any error but not able to load it into blob column.